# Any information on this secret / hidden cave in A Coruña, Spain?

Tags: spain, identify-this

There's what 'may be' ( don't know ! ) an intentionally secret / hidden cave in A Coruña' city in Spain. Is there any information about it anywhere ?

- It's on public land, right next to, and below, the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarium_Finisterrae but does not seem to be in any way connected to the Aquarium Finisterrae.
- It has had two large boulders intentionally placed in front of it, either, so that fewer people will notice the cave, or, to prevent the cave or coast being eroded by storm waves etc.
- At some time, a square window was cut into the very thick side of the cave . ( the window can be seen to be square shaped, when viewed from adequate angle and sufficient lighting )
- It does not seem to be mentioned anywhere on the internet https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playa_de_Las_Lapas

Unfortunately I cannot obtain better photos of it.

When looking at it in person from the other side of the bay, you can clearly see it is a cave, and the window ( The window can be seen to be square shaped, when  viewed from adequate angle and sufficient lighting ) .

**QUESTION**
Is there any information about this cave anywhere ( webpage ) ?

NOTE - Due to an odd technical problem, I cannot post any comments .

NOTE - I just added 2 images, from earlier years, a zoom-in of an image from earlier years, and that image without zoom-in, the window or whatever, is clearly / definitely man made .
Remember that you can just click on any image and look at it on another browser-tab, and magnify it, through your browser etc.

NOTE - One possible explanation 'may be', that during storms ( or higher tides ) , the waves 'may' crash against the mouth of the cave, and without a vent, the sudden compression of air in there could cause loud explosion like sounds that may disturb the Aquarium, or even cause cracks etc, so maybe that window is a vent to prevent that.
I assume that what look like holes, above, and to the left of the 'window', are not anything, since it seems they also occur at various other 'insignificant' parts of the rocks.

- The Zoom-in of the image from earlier years, is the 2nd image .

[image: Image taken in recent years]

[image: Zoom-in of image from earlier years]

[image: Image from earlier years]

[image]

Comment: Have you actually been to this cave? The 'cave window' looks to me like a hole, not necessarily connected to the cave, and the boulders like they're part of the sea defences placed along the wall. I'm not convinced there's anything secret or concealed here.

Comment: They are just shadows, which you can imagine to be anything you like from a distance.

Comment: Re edit: the new image you show is definitely not a cave: you can see rock in the shade, not a void. It looks more like a slight overhang as a result of erosion, which is evident from the retaining wall and protective rocks piled nearby. The window looks "man made" because of the photo process edge highlighting. You can see the edges of all the rocks near the "window" have edge highlights too. If you have been there at least twice, why don't you go and have a look next time? There are millions of unremarkable caves and overhangs around the coasts. Nice imagination, though.

Comment: It could really just be an underground part of the aquarium above, and some kind of vent or similar man-made opening...

Comment: To me, some of the aquarium buildings look old military style, which wouldnt be out of the question given the location - it wouldnt surprise me if anything under there is to do with any formwr military use which has now ended.

Comment: It's clear from the photographs the OP has added that there's no cave. The 'window', whilst it looks superficially to be man made, could be almost anything, but almost certainly nothing noteworthy. Voting to close.

Comment: geocaching.com has several caches listed nearby, but apparently none in that cave. Seems surprising that there is none in that cave if it is puiblicly accessible :) (A mystery cache is nearby but has too low terrain difficulty to be ending up in such a cave)

Answer (score -2):

Though I am not from Galicia myself I have been there many times and have very good friends in Galicia. They told me once in the area near La Torre de Hercules percebeiros risk their lives to obtain the precious percebes seafood.

When I´ve read your question it made me guess if maybe this is something conected to the activity of percebeiros to store fishing accesories. You should also bear in mind that legal percebeiros with persmission to fish find the competition of ilegal fishermen. So maybe the cave is used by these. I am just guessing here, have no real answer!

I leave an article from a galician neewspaper where they mention about the fights between legal and illegal percebeiros

https://www.elidealgallego.com/articulo/coruna/detienen-furtivos-actuaron-zona-vedada-torre-dias-seguidos/20190618225258408401.html

Hope this helps
Luis

Comment: Hi Luis and thanks for your recent answers. This doesn't really look like an actual answer to the question to me, nor does your now deleted answer. We are different from other sites and this isn't a forum. For more information please read the [tour] and [how do I write a good answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  You can also have a look at [the highest voted answers on the site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa) to see what good answers look like. I hope you continue to contribute quality answers on the site.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I understand this comment. The answer I have provided tries to explain why the cave may exist. The place where the cave is located is full of activities from a type of fishermen in Spain known as percebeiros. Ther is no translation in English of this word. Percebiros may have built that cave or if not them it could have been illegal percebeiros trying to hide what they get. It takes some knowledge of this reality to judge my answer as useless. I think it can be the anwers...

Comment: I didn't say your answer was useless. Your answers seem to be written as if this site is a forum; it is not. Have you read the tour and how do I write a good answer pages that I linked to in my previous comment? In your answer, you state: "I am just guessing here, have no real answer!". You may not have an answer to every question. But as we are not a forum, we do try and not answer questions that we don't have a real definitive answer to.

Comment: ok, thanks. Ill try to be more helpful in future ocassions